# Get Specific Information From HTML Data String

Tags: php, web-scraping

I have a data coming in following format that's assigned to variable $data in which I am only trying to get `Product Description` and `Ingredients` and assign them to a variable `$pdesc` & `$ingredient`. Is there a way in PHP to extract this specific information? so in following example.

```
$pdesc should contain "<p>It can help improve brain and memory function</p>
  <p>Its good for health</p>"  
$ingredients should contain "<p>Lecithin (product of soya), Gelatin, Glycerine.  </p>"
```

---

```
$data = '<div id="productDescription">

  <div class="disclaim">

    Size:<strong>90</strong>

  </div>

  <h3>Product Description</h3>
  <p>It can help improve brain and memory function</p>
  <p>Its good for health</p>

  <h3>Indications</h3>

  <p>Do not exceed the recommended intake.  </p>

  <h3>Ingredients</h3>

  <p>Lecithin (product of soya), Gelatin, Glycerine.  </p>

  <h3>Directions</h3>

  <p>Take 1 - 2 softgels per day with food.  </p>

  <h3>Box Contains</h3>

  <p>1 x Natures Aid 1200mg Soya Lecithin 90 Capsules</p>

</div>'
```

Comment: You'll probably want to look into [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: Maybe you can use regular expression to extract the tags.